# How do I split authors into a XML list

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to generate a XML with multiple authors from a given string inside a html-file. The string is fetched through the help of XPATH and stored in a string-List. The XML is generated through a class constructor.

Original html

```
<meta name="DC.Creator" content="Gareth Jones, Alexander M. Robertson, Chawchat Santimetvirul, Peter Willett">
```

I need help splitting the authors into first and last name strings, and then generate a pre-defined XML for each author, and to end the the last XML-snippet with a closing '),'

XML-snippet

```
new XElement("author",
new XAttribute("primary_contact", "false"),
new XAttribute("include_in_browser", "true"),
new XAttribute("user_group_ref", "Authors"),
new XElement("firstname", AuthorData.FirstName),
new XElement("lastname", AuthorData.LastName),
new XElement("email", AuthorData.Email))), <-- Note the ending ), for the last author in list
```

How do I split each authour into a XML-snippet?

Here is a Pastebin of the complete program, https://pastebin.com/sx0H7MFd

Here is the full code (sorry for long post)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace XML_Template_Generator
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Global
        {
            // vars
            public static string AllFilesExtension = "*.*";
            public static string HtmlExtension = "*.html";
            public static string JpgExtension = "*.jpg";
            public static string GifExtension = "*.gif";
            public static string PngExtension = "*.png";
            public static string ArchiveDirectory = @"D:\Journals\";
            public static string Directory = @"D:\Journals\1-1";

        }

        public class AuthorData
        {
            public AuthorData(string firstName, string lastName, string email)
            {
                FirstName = firstName;
                LastName = lastName;
                Email = email;
            }
            public static string FirstName { get; set; }
            public static string LastName { get; set; }
            public static string Email { get; set; }
        }

        public class XmlGenerator
        {
            public static string[] htmlFilelist = Directory.GetFiles(Global.Directory, Global.HtmlExtension);

            // Issue and article specific strings
            public static string Title = "";
            public static string Description = "";
            public static string AuthorsFirstname = AuthorData.FirstName;
            public static string AuthorsLastname = AuthorData.LastName;
            public static string AuthorEmail = AuthorData.Email;
            public static string Publisher = "";
            public static string PrimaryAuthorFirstname = "";
            public static string PrimaryAuthorLastname = "";
            public static string PrimaryAuthorEmail = "info@email.se";

            public static string XmlConstructor(){

                // XML constructor
                XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
                XDocument xmldocument = new XDocument(
                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                    new XComment("Creating the issues and articles tree for import"),
                    new XElement("issues",
                        new XElement("issue",
                            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                            new XAttribute("published", true),
                            new XAttribute("current", false),
                            new XAttribute("access_status", "1"),
                            new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://dev.openjournal.tld native.xsd"),
                            new XElement("id",
                                new XAttribute("type", "internal"),
                                new XAttribute("advice", "ignore"), "4"),
                            new XElement("description",
                                new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), Description),
                            new XElement("issue_identification",
                                new XElement("volume", 1),
                                new XElement("number", 1),
                                new XElement("year", 1995),
                                new XElement("title", Title,
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en-us"))),
                            new XElement("date_published", "2018-05-16"),
                            new XElement("last_modified", "2018-05-16"),
                            new XElement("sections",
                                new XElement("section",
                                    new XAttribute("ref", "ART"),
                                    new XAttribute("seq", 0),
                                    new XAttribute("editor_restricted", 0),
                                    new XAttribute("meta_indexed", 1),
                                    new XAttribute("abstracts_not_required", 0),
                                    new XAttribute("hide_title", 0),
                                    new XAttribute("hide_author", 0),
                                    new XAttribute("abstract_word_count", 0)),
                                new XElement("id",
                                    new XAttribute("type", "internal"),
                                    new XAttribute("advice", "ignore")),
                                new XElement("abbrev",
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), "ART"),
                                new XElement("title",
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), "Artiklar")),
                            new XElement("issue_covers",
                                new XElement("cover",
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en_US")),
                                new XElement("cover_image", "cover_issue_4_en_US.jpg"),
                                new XElement("cover_image_alt_text")),
                            new XElement("issue_galleys",
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                                new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://dev.openjournal.tld native.xsd"),
                                new XElement("issue_galley",
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"),
                                    new XElement("label", "Paper1"),
                                    from f in htmlFilelist
                                    select new XElement("issue_file",
                                        new XElement("file_name", f),
                                        new XElement("file_type", "text/html"),
                                        new XElement("file_size", "FILE SIZE"),
                                        new XElement("file_size", "FILE SIZE"),
                                        new XElement("content_type", 1),
                                        new XElement("original_file_name", "FILE NAME"),
                                        new XElement("date_uploaded", "2018-05-16"),
                                        new XElement("date_modified", "2018-05-16")))),
                            new XElement("articles",
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                                new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://dev.openjournal.tld native.xsd"),
                                new XElement("article",
                                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi",
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                                    new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"),
                                    new XAttribute("date_submitted", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                                    new XAttribute("stage", "production"),
                                    new XAttribute("date_published", "1995-01-01"),
                                    new XAttribute("section_ref", "ART"),
                                    new XAttribute("seq", 1),
                                    new XAttribute("access_status", 0),
                                    new XElement("id",
                                        new XAttribute("type", "internal"),
                                        new XAttribute("advice", "ignore"), 5),
                                    new XElement("title",
                                        new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), Title),
                                    new XElement("abstract",
                                        new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), Description),
                                    new XElement("licenseUrl", "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0"),
                                    new XElement("copyrightHolder",
                                        new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), "INSERT NAME OF COPYRIGHT HOLDER HERE"),
                                    new XElement("copyrightYear", "INSERT YEAR HERE"),
                                    new XElement("keywords",
                                        new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"),
                                        new XElement("keyword", "HOW DO I GET MULTIPLE KEYWORDS?")),
                                    new XElement("authors",
                                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi",
                                            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                                        new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://dev.openjournal.tld native.xsd"),
                                        new XElement("author",
                                            new XAttribute("primary_contact", "true"),
                                            new XAttribute("include_in_browser", "true"),
                                            new XAttribute("user_group_ref", "Authors"),
                                            new XElement("firstname", PrimaryAuthorFirstname),
                                            new XElement("lastname", PrimaryAuthorLastname),
                                            new XElement("email", PrimaryAuthorEmail)),
                                        new XElement("author",
                                            new XAttribute("primary_contact", "false"),
                                            new XAttribute("include_in_browser", "true"),
                                            new XAttribute("user_group_ref", "Authors"),
                                            new XElement("firstname", AuthorData.FirstName),
                                            new XElement("lastname", AuthorData.LastName),
                                            new XElement("email", AuthorData.Email))),
                                    new XElement("submission_file",
                                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi",
                                            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                                        new XAttribute("id", "INSERT ID HERE"),
                                        new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://dev.openjournal.tld native.xsd"),
                                        new XElement("revision",
                                            new XAttribute("number", "1"),
                                            new XAttribute("genre", "ARTIKELTEXT"),
                                            new XAttribute("filename", "INSERT FILENAME HERE"),
                                            new XAttribute("date_uploaded", "INSERT DATE FOR UPLOAD HERE"),
                                            new XAttribute("date_modified", "INSERT DATE FOR LAST MODIFICATION HERE"),
                                            new XAttribute("filesize", "INSERT FILE SIZE HERE (MIGHT BE OPTIONAL)"),
                                            new XAttribute("filetype", "INSERT TYPE OF FILE text/html OR PICTURES"),
                                            new XAttribute("user_group", "Authors"),
                                            new XAttribute("uploader", "INSERT FIRST AUTHOR AS UPLOADER HERE"),
                                            new XElement("name",
                                                new XAttribute("locale", "en_US"), "AUTHORSNAME, USER_GROUP, FILENAME"),
                                            new XElement("href",
                                                new XAttribute("src", "http://localhost/importfolder/papers.html"),
                                                new XAttribute("mime_type", "text/url"))
                                        )))))));
                return xmldocument.ToString();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // list all directory paths. Use in a foreach-loop to select each directory.
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Global.ArchiveDirectory, Global.AllFilesExtension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            // List all files and types in invidual lists
            string[] htmlFilelist = XmlGenerator.htmlFilelist;
            var jpgFilelist = Getfile(Global.Directory, Global.JpgExtension);
            var gifFilelist = Getfile(Global.Directory, Global.GifExtension);
            var pngFilelist = Getfile(Global.Directory, Global.PngExtension);

            // Read every file in list and find information with XPath
            foreach (string file in htmlFilelist)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.Load(file);
                HtmlNodeNavigator navigator = (HtmlNodeNavigator) doc.CreateNavigator();

                // Get the title for the file
                string title_xpath = "//meta[@name='DC.Title']/@content";
                XmlGenerator.Title = navigator.SelectSingleNode(title_xpath).Value;

                // Get the description of the document
                string description_xpath = "//meta[@name='DC.Description']/@content";
                XmlGenerator.Description = navigator.SelectSingleNode(description_xpath).Value;

                // Get the author or authors in to a list
                string author_xpath = "//meta[@name='DC.Creator']/@content";
                var authors = new List<string>();
                string[] author = navigator.SelectSingleNode(author_xpath).Value.Split(',');
                foreach (var a in author)
                {
                    authors.Add(a);
                }

                // Split their names into first and lastname
                var authorName = authors.First().Split(' ');

                // Get the publisher meta tag
                string publisher_xpath = "//meta[@name='DC.Publisher']/@content";
                XmlGenerator.Publisher = navigator.SelectSingleNode(publisher_xpath).Value;

                // Test for co-authors names
                AuthorData.FirstName = "Kalle";
                AuthorData.LastName = "Andersson";
                AuthorData.Email = "authors@email.com";

                // Test with output to console
                Console.WriteLine("*** Authors ***");
                foreach (var a in authors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", file);
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", XmlGenerator.Title);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", XmlGenerator.Description);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Primary Author: {0} {1}", authorName[0], authorName[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("Primary Author Email: {0}", XmlGenerator.PrimaryAuthorEmail);
                Console.WriteLine("Publisher: {0}", XmlGenerator.Publisher);
                Console.WriteLine("********");
                }

            // Output to console for testing
            Console.WriteLine("Total number of directories: {0}", dirs.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of html-files: {0}", htmlFilelist.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of jpg-files: {0}", jpgFilelist.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of gif-files: {0}", gifFilelist.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of png-files: {0}", pngFilelist.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("*** XML ***");
            Console.WriteLine(XmlGenerator.XmlConstructor());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static IEnumerable<string> Getfile(string fdir, string ext)
        {
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(fdir, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return files;
        }
        static List<string> build_directory_list(string dir)
        {
            // Get all subdirectories
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();
            foreach (string directory in subdirectories)
            {
                directories.Add(directory);
            }
            return directories;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: Can I assume you've already managed to read the content attribute with the author names?

Comment: are you looking for string.split or regexp to split the author names and then into first and last names ?

Comment: @Fabulous Yes, the authors names are read into a List with the help of a XPATH. They are separated by the comma. But they need to be split into first and last name as well. Not sure how to approach that the best way.

Comment: What did you try? Splitting by comma certainly is an easy task, splitting by last blank might be a line more...

Comment: @mjwills Please check updated question. I added link to pastebin with the complete program.

Comment: It would be awesome if the code was in the question. Most people won't click external links.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already got the string with the author names. Here is one way to get all the authors using a linq query. I have wrapped these in a containing `XElement` to conform to xml standard but you could do them separately if you wish.

```
var content = "Gareth Jones, Alexander M. Robertson, Chawchat Santimetvirul, Peter Willett";
var names = content.Split(',');
Array.ForEach(names, Console.WriteLine);

var authors = new XElement("authors",
    names.Select(x => new XElement("author",
        new XAttribute("primary_contact", "false"),
        new XAttribute("include_in_browser", "true"),
        new XAttribute("user_group_reg", "Authors"),
        new XElement("firstname", x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1).Trim()),
        new XElement("lastname", x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1)),
        new XElement("email", "dude@work.com")
        )));
```

**Update**

I have left my original answer in place (and I'm back at my PC so I can respond in detail). Considering the new requirements in your comment below, I have included how to give a list of individual author elements and also how to make the first one the primary contact with the others having that attribute set to false. See the following code:

```
var authorCount = 1; // Used to determine whether this is the primary contact.
IEnumerable<XElement> authors = names
    .Select(x => new XElement("author",
        new XAttribute("primary_contact", authorCount++ == 1),
        new XAttribute("include_in_browser", true),
        new XAttribute("user_group_reg", "Authors"),
        new XElement("firstname", x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim()),
        new XElement("lastname", x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1)),
        new XElement("email", "dude@work.com")
    ));
// Display to console.
Array.ForEach(authors.ToArray(), Console.WriteLine);
```

That should give you the list formatted as you have specified.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll test it out later today. Thank you for answering, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi again, how can I exclude the node authors (plural)? I only need to set the first author in list as the primary, and the rest will have "primary_contact" set to false. Seems a bit tricky to get it right... :)

Comment: to exclude the top node, define it as follows: `var authors = names.Select(x => XElement("author",...)` This will give you an `IEnumerable<XElement>` that you can work with. I'll get back to you on setting primary contact for the first one only.

Comment: @ChristerJohansson I have updated my answer to include what you have asked for.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            string authors = "Gareth Jones, Alexander M. Robertson, Chawchat Santimetvirul, Peter Willett";
            string[] authorArray = authors.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();

            XElement xAuthors = new XElement("Authors");
            foreach (string author in authorArray)
            {
                XElement xAuthor = new XElement("author",
                    new XAttribute("primary_contact", "false"),
                    new XAttribute("include_in_browser", "true"),
                    new XAttribute("user_group_ref", "Authors"),
                    author
                    );
                xAuthors.Add(xAuthor);
            }
```

Comment: Very good, I'll experiment with this during the day. Thank you for answering, much appreciated. :)